# ListView com um botão no final da lista android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Boa tarde,
Tenho um ListView que esta trazendo alguns dados, esta funcionando sem problemas. Mas no final da lista, preciso colocar um botão. Esse botão não deve se repetir, como esta acontecendo. Coloquei o mesmo dentro do xml de layout da lista.

Comment: Por favor, poste o seu arquivo .xml com o layout, irá ajudar a entender o problema e chegar numa solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar um Float Button e isolar a sua ListView em um Linear Layout, exemplo:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

A linha:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
```

Vai ser responsável por deixar o Float Button la no canto inferior direito, uma vez só.

Answer (score 0):

tens de criar um relative layout, e depois metes o botao encostado em baixo, depois metes a lista, mas com a tag above, assim primeiro entra o butao e depois a lista que tem de ficar em cima do botao

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:divider="@null"
         android:layout_above="@id/button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```